# How to load a model in Autoload file in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

How can I load a model in **...\app\Config\Autoload.php**?

Code:

```
namespace Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\AutoloadConfig;

class Autoload extends AutoloadConfig {

    public function __construct() {
         //load here
         //i've tried,
         $my_model = new \App\Models\My_model();
         $my_model = model("App\Models\My_model");
    }
```

Nothing is working.

What is the correct way?

Looking for help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This really depends on where you want to use this model. Autoloading does not work the same way as codeigniter 3 where everything would be put into the same super object.

If what you want is to use this model in a bunch of controllers then you can add that to your baseController in your initController function. Let's say you want to autoload the article model:

```
public $article;

public function initController(\CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface $request, \CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface $response, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    // Do Not Edit This Line
    parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);
    $this->article = new \App\Models\ArticleModel();
}
```

Now all your controllers that extend to your baseController can access this model with $this->article.

If what you want is to use the autoload and you can do that too, but not in a construct, for that you should use the classMap property.

```
 /**
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Class Map
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 * The class map provides a map of class names and their exact
 * location on the drive. Classes loaded in this manner will have
 * slightly faster performance because they will not have to be
 * searched for within one or more directories as they would if they
 * were being autoloaded through a namespace.
 *
 * Prototype:
 *
 *   $classmap = [
 *       'MyClass'   => '/path/to/class/file.php'
 *   ];
 *
 * @var array
 */
public $classmap = [
    'Article' => APPPATH . 'Models/ArticleModel.php'
];
```

But this option is more for classes that exist outside the normal codeigniter structure. So I would advise into using the first option.

Comment: Actually I want to get a model in the `__construct()` of `Autoload` class. I don't want to load it everywhere. Just in the __construct function.

Comment: Why do you need the model just in that construct?

Comment: I've to push some data to **$psr4** variable dynamically. That's why I need the model there. Is there any other way to do that?